# Java Kerberos set delegate flag using logincontext

Tags: java, kerberos

I am using the apache httpcomponents 4.5.3. and the java Krb5LoginModule to handle Kerberos authentication to IIS.  IIS is set to only accept Kerberos authentication.  This is working as expected for the single hop scenario.  I need to have the kerberos ticket marked as "ok to delegate" so it will go from IIS to an SSAS server.  I have a python and .net library working with Kerberos on the same IIS server, so I know that it works.  The java library needs to have the "ok to delegate" flag set, but I cannot figure out how to set it.  I am using java's logincontext and apache's httpclient to make the calls.

To give you an idea of the code, here it is:

```
LoginContext context = null;

try {
    // Create a LoginContext with a callback handler
    context = new LoginContext(name, callbackHandler);

    // Perform authentication
    context.login();
} catch (LoginException e) {
    System.err.println("Login failed");
    e.printStackTrace();
    System.exit(-1);
}


// Perform action as authenticated user
Subject subject = context.getSubject();
if (verbose) {
    System.out.println(subject.toString());
} else {
    System.out.println("Authenticated principal: " +
            subject.getPrincipals());
}

Subject.doAs(subject, action);
```

Comment: What kind of "delegation" do you want -- the one which uses *proxiable* tickets, or the one which uses *forwardable* tickets? Cf. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc961964.aspx

Comment: Anyway, AFAIK, the `kinit.exe` shipped with the Sun/Oracle JDK supports flags for creating "proxiable" and/or "forwardable" tickets (in a file cache) cf. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/kinit.html >> but Java itself uses the options defined in the Kerberos conf file, cf. https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-4460829

Comment: Note that on Windows, AFAIK, if `KRB5_CONFIG` env variable does not point to a specific conf file, then Java falls back to whatever Active Directory config is used by the OS. Also, if `KRB5CCNAME` does not point to a specific ticket cache file, and if the default cache file name does not point to a valid cache, then Java will fall back to the current Windows credentials _(if the cache is queriable - open by default on workstations, closed by default on Servers)_ -- which I guess are not forwardable/proxiable.

Comment: Ah, an exception to the cache rules -- if you use a custom JAAS config file for that specific "subject", then you can *(a)* specify a custom cache file name or *(b)* require that no cache will be used -- i.e. that Java should create a private ticket for the current session, either with a keytab file or a prompt for password -- cf. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/jre/api/security/jaas/spec/com/sun/security/auth/module/Krb5LoginModule.html

Comment: I am looking to mark the ticket as "ok-to-delegate", so my java application authenticates with IIS (working) and IIS authenticates as me to the SSAS server (not working).  In Python, I have to set the delegate flag for it to work.  .Net works.  I just need the "ok-to-delegate" set so that IIS can request a ticket on my behalf to the SSAS server.

Comment: If that weird "ok-to-delegate" thing is a specific Microsoft extension *(Active Directory tickets carry extra stuff compared to barebones Kerberos tickets)*, and not a standard Kerberos feature, then Java does not support it. If it is a SPNEGO feature on top of the Kerberos auth, then maybe it's an Apache lib problem.

Comment: So, Java does not support Kerberos delegation?  To be clear, a java application uses Kerberos to connect to a service.  That service uses the user's Kerberos ticket on it's behalf to get a ticket for the next service.  This would mean that Java does not support double hop scenarios, which seems like a big issue.

I find it strange that Python does support this type of Kerberos ticket.

Comment: *sigh*... Kerberos was around **decades** before Microsoft realized that their NTLM stuff was a failure, and they had to retrofit Kerberos into Active Directory. But they already had their own concept of "delegation". So they added some custom extensions -- and custom vocabulary -- to plain Kerberos. Java supports (most of) Kerberos. But **Java does not support the Microsoft AD nonsense**. And I would not bet that Python on Linux would support the AD nonsense, either; just like Curl-on-Windows uses Microsoft SSPI libs (like .Net) while Curl-on-Linux uses GSSAPI libs.

Comment: You are actually incorrect.  Python on Linux does support delegation using the Microsoft AD nonsense.  in fact, I use the requests-kerberos library for Python and it works excellent from Linux.  I am just amazed that Java does not have the support for it..yet.

Comment: Here is what makes it work in Python:  
kerberos_auth = HTTPKerberosAuth(principal=self._principal, mutual_authentication=REQUIRED, sanitize_mutual_error_response=False, delegate=True)

Comment: _"I am just amazed that Java does not have the support for it."_ > IMHO it's not a Java issue, but rather an ApacheHTTP issue. Did you consider using another lib?

Answer (score 0):

The solution I used for **quick and dirty** was to update the apache httpcomponents library.  I downloaded the source code and modified one line of code to make the double hop scenario work.  In the class GGSSchemeBase.java, the function createGSSContext, I added a line at line no 138, which reads:

```
gssContext.requestCredDeleg(true);
```

This now forces every kerberos interaction to create a ticket with credential delegation.  For my needs, this is sufficient.  Ideally, one of the higher level classes could be modified to take in additional GSS flags.  However, that is a fight for another day.

Answer (score 0):

As state [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HTTPCLIENT-1736), you can extends the SPNegoScheme class (which extends GGSSchemeBase) and override the method generateGSSToken which calls createGSSContext. You have to create a new createGSSContext method and add 'gssContext.requestCredDeleg(true);'.

Then you can create your HttpClient with a builder like this:

```
    HttpClientBuilder builder = HttpClientBuilder.create();
    Lookup<AuthSchemeProvider> authSchemeRegistry = RegistryBuilder.<AuthSchemeProvider>create().register(AuthSchemes.SPNEGO, new YourOwnSPNegoSchemeFactory()).build();
    builder.setDefaultAuthSchemeRegistry(authSchemeRegistry);
```

YourOwnSPNegoSchemaFactory is a class which extends SPNegoSchemaFactory and is capable of creating and instantiating your own extension of SPNegoSchema.